# Iterating over json object programmatically with Handlebars

Tags: json, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I have some json that looks like this:

```
{{...},
"skills": [{
        "languages": ["Java", "JavaScript", "C", "HTML5", "CSS3", "PHP", "Python"],
        "j2ee": ["JSP", "Struts", "Tiles"],
        "servers": ["Apache Tomcat 5, 6", "Webshpere Application Server", "Node.js", "Django (Python framework)"],
        "tools": ["Eclipse and Rational Application Developer", "Maven", "vim", "*nix CLI"],
        "versions": ["Git", "MKS", "Accurev", "SubVersion", "CVS"]
}], 
{...}}
```

and some handlebars in a partial that looks like this:

```
{{#each skills}}
<div id="{{this}}">
<ul>
    {{#list this}}
    <li>{{this}}</li>
    {{/list}}
</ul>
</div>
{{/each}}
```

This obviously does not work, but my thought process was that I could iterate over the `skills` array programmatically so that I wouldn't have to put the keys in, and then iterate over each key's value (an array).

I know I could just do something like

```
{"skills": 
    [{"name": "languages", 
      "values":["Java",...]},
     {"name": "j2ee", 
      "values":["JSP",...]},
     {...}]}
```

but I'm wondering if there's a way to do it with the first structure.

Comment: Handlebars wants to iterate over arrays. Iterating over an object for display purposes makes little sense in JavaScript as objects are unordered. Rework your data before it hits the template and move on to more interesting problems.